# undocumented tweet escaping?

Tags: twitter, escaping

I found some character like "<" ">" "&" in tweet being automatically escaped by twitter.

For example, tweeting with content `<>&` will result in `&lt;&gt;&amp;` despite the content is serialized to JSON object.

I've searched a lot but found no official document describing this behavior.

Where can I get a full list of escape characters?